# 404 When Posting to Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure

I am attempting to write to Azure Table Storage without using the TableContext and Table ServiceEntity classes, I just want to send raw XML (I want the flexibility of defining the schema on the fly).

When I do this (and sign the request using the method in the SDK) I get a 404. No idea why.

The table exists. I have omitted my credentials, but they are correct in my original code.

The code snippet below illustrates the problem.

Any suggestions are very welcome!

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Protocol;

public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Credentials credentials = new Credentials("xxx", @"yyy");
        var uri = string.Format(@"http://{0}.table.core.windows.net/{1}(PartitionKey='{2}',RowKey='{3}')", credentials.AccountName, "TableName", "1", "1");
        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "2.0;NetFx");
        webRequest.Headers.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "2.0;NetFx");
        webRequest.ContentType = @"application/atom+xml";
        WriteToRequestStream(uri, webRequest);
        TableRequest.SignRequestForSharedKeyLite(webRequest, credentials);
        var response = webRequest.GetResponse(); // 404 thrown here
    }

    private static void WriteToRequestStream(string uri, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?><entry xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'><title /><updated>2009-03-18T11:48:34.9840639-07:00</updated><author><name /></author><id>");
        sb.Append(uri);
        sb.Append(@"</id><content type='application/xml'><m:properties></m:properties></content></entry>");
        string body = sb.ToString();
        webRequest.ContentLength = body.Length;
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(body);
        using (Stream requestStream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what operation are you trying to perform? it looks like an entity update, but the HTTP method for that is PUT, which would explain the error

Comment: Good question, I'm trying to create an entity. However, if I change PUT to POST, I get the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried writing to the same table through the storage client library?  If that fails it might point to something outside of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an entity, you have three choices:

1. [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179433.aspx) in which you POST to `http://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable`
2. [Insert or Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452241.aspx) in which you MERGE to `http://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey="myPartitionKey", RowKey="myRowKey1")`
3. [Insert or Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452242.aspx) in which you PUT to `http://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable(PartitionKey="myPartitionKey", RowKey="myRowKey1")`

The latter two, however, are not supported by the local emulator.

Additionally, I took a look at the request your code is making using Fiddler, and it's missing the following headers:

- Authorization
- Date or x-ms-date
- x-ms-version

To include the headers correctly, try this code:

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
webRequest.Method = "PUT";
webRequest.Headers.Add("DataServiceVersion", "2.0;NetFx");
webRequest.Headers.Add("MaxDataServiceVersion", "2.0;NetFx");
webRequest.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2011-08-18");
webRequest.ContentType = @"application/atom+xml";
TableRequest.SignRequestForSharedKeyLite(webRequest, credentials);
WriteToRequestStream(uri, webRequest);
var response = webRequest.GetResponse();
```

Notice how I changed the method to do an Insert or Replace. I also inverted the call to `SignRequestForSharedKeyLite` and added a `x-ms-version` header with version `2011-08-18` otherwise Insert or Replace is not supported.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried altering the code to all of those variations, and I'm still getting 404 for everything I try.

Comment: Yes, your ammended answer is abosultely right, the problem was that I was signing the headers after writing to the response body. Writing to the body will flush the headers through, so the header with the signature is never sent. So simply moving the signing up a couple of lines fixes the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See type limitations for table storage on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179338.aspx . When for instance posting a property with a minimum datatime value it will result in a 404

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the 'x-ms-date' header.  I believe that header is required (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179433.aspx).

It might be worth checking out http://azurestoragesamples.codeplex.com/ for full examples on using the REST API.  Most operations are included there.

Comment: Thanks, I *think* that 'SignRequestForSharedKeyLite' adds this, but I'll check.